# How to reduce and get value from object array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to reduce object array which is as below:
`arr=[{title: 'AP', CurrentDate: 2019-07-31, Status: 'done', NoOfEvents:'6' }]`

Now I want to reduce this array object to get `NoOfEvents` value.

So I am trying below code but it's not working:

`arr.reduce((n,x) => n + (x.title === 'AP' && new Date(x.CurrentDate) > (2019-05-15) + x.NoOfEvents,null)`

How do I get value of `NoOfEvents` based on above condition in reduce?

Comment: why do you want to use reduce if you only need `NoOfEvents` value based on condition

Comment: what is the result you are getting..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function wrote is wrongly formed. You can try the following way.

```js
const arr = [{title: 'AP', CurrentDate: '2019-07-31', Status: 'done', NoOfEvents:'6' }]
const result = arr.reduce((n, x) => (n += (x.title === 'AP' && new Date(x.CurrentDate) > new Date('2019-05-15')) ? +x.NoOfEvents: 0, n), 0)
console.log(result)
```